# How is it possible to send ping to all 127.0.0.0/8 successfully?

Tags: networking, internet, network-interface, private-network

I have some wonders about 127.0.0.0/8 network and have 2 question about it.

Firstly, why 127.0.0.0/8 is not considered as private network? I wonder this because [wiki page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network) does not mention about it. Where 127.0.0.0/8 differs from other private networks?

Secondly, I realized I can send ping successfully to all IP addresses in 127.0.0.0/8, just like lo interface has all this IP addresses. What is the technical reason of this case?

Comment: Usually a "network" is considered something that **several** systems are connected to.